How to prevent localhost prefixes being added to the link
I am trying to add an iframe which shows the content of another html document to my current html document using this code:
display.innerHTML = '<iframe id="externalFrame" src="viewpage.html" style="width:80%; height: 700px;"></iframe><br><button class="button color" onclick="sendSelected();">Finish</button>';
I am using react and the current HTML document runs on http://localhost:3000/ However, somehow the prefix http://localhost:3000/ is being added automatically to the src in the iframe so it would look like this: http://localhost:3000/viewpage.html. That link points to the current page itself so basically the iframe shows the current html page within the current html page. How do I fix this?
I tried to use an absolute path from the C drive to the wanted HTML document, but the iframe showed a blank page and I don't want to use this method since I want to deploy my website later on. I used the live server extension in vscode to host that second HTML document and put the link to the HTML document inside src in iframe. It solved the problem but that would mean I need to deploy 2 separate html pages during deployment.

I'm guessing that your src is using a relative path since you're not prefixing it with /. You should change to src="/path-to-viewpage-from-root/viewpage.html".

I tried "/viewpage.html" it does not work. What do you mean by root here?

@longlegedcorgi I mean the root of your project. So if you have a file system like
src
folder1
viewpage.html
you need to do /src/folder1/viewpage.html
or you can use ../viewpage.html or your relative path
